# Connect MySQL using SSL only with the --ssl-ca option

Tags: mysql, percona

I copied the `ca.pem` from server (Percona default 5.7 Ubuntu deb) able to make a secure connection with

```
mysql  --ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem -u root
```

I find that the options `--ssl-cert` and `--ssl-key` are actually no needed.

What are the drawbacks in doing so?

Comment: it is likely that all of those elements are bundled into ca.pem

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion of this in this blog post, as things changed with 5.7.3: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/06/27/ssl-connections-in-mysql-5-7/

The link in that post, though, has changed as I think the documentation may have been updated. This is a better page from the core manual to view (referenced from the CREATE USER syntax page):  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connections.html.  From the manual:

> As of MySQL 5.7.3, a client need specify only the --ssl option to obtain an
>   encrypted connection. The connection attempt fails if an encrypted connection
>   cannot be established. Before MySQL 5.7.3, the client must specify either the 
>   --ssl-ca option, or all three of the --ssl-ca, --ssl-key, and --ssl-cert options.

As you can see, before 5.7.3 the client must specify either --ssl-ca OR all three. There is a full discussion in the MySQL documentation.

*Disclosure: I work for Percona*

Comment: So, after 5.7.3, I don't need to have any ca/cert/key files and I was able to make connection using SSL? (if I don't care the client identity)

Comment: There is more explanation of the --ssl option here, as it depends on whether the connection is client or server side (and --ssl is deprecated client side from MySQL 8 in favour of --ssl-mode), but implies that yes. 

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-options.html#option_general_ssl

info on --ssl-mode  

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-options.html#option_general_ssl